# Image is not retrieved in ImageView of RecyclerView from Firebase

Tags: android, image, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
    public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
    private static final int RC_PHOTO_PICKER = 2;
    private String mUsername;

    // Firebase instance variables
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mMessagesDatabaseReference;
    private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
    private FirebaseStorage mFirebaseStorage;
    private StorageReference mChatPhotosStorageReference;
    private FirebaseRemoteConfig mFirebaseRemoteConfig;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;

    PhotosAdapter contactsAdapter;
    List<Photos> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        floatingActionButton=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.floatingactionbutton);
        contactList = new ArrayList();
        contactsAdapter=new PhotosAdapter(contactList,getApplicationContext());

        // Initialize Firebase components
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();


        mMessagesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("messages");
        mChatPhotosStorageReference = mFirebaseStorage.getReference().child("chat_photos");

        mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    onSignedInInitialize(user.getDisplayName());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    onSignedOutCleanup();
                    startActivityForResult(
                            AuthUI.getInstance()
                                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                    .setProviders(
                                            AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER,
                                            AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER)
                                    .build(),
                            RC_SIGN_IN);
                }
            }
        };

        recyclerView.setAdapter(contactsAdapter);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),5));


        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Sign-in succeeded, set up the UI
                Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Sign in was canceled by the user, finish the activity
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }else if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            // Get a reference to store file at chat_photos/<FILENAME>
            StorageReference photoRef = mChatPhotosStorageReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

            // Upload file to Firebase Storage
            photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get its download URL
                            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                            // Set the download URL to the message box, so that the user can send it to the database
                            Photos friendlyMessage = new Photos(downloadUrl.toString());
                            mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mAuthStateListener != null) {
            mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
        }
    }

         private void onSignedInInitialize(String username) {
        mUsername = username;
        attachDatabaseReadListener();
    }

    private void onSignedOutCleanup() {
        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;

    }

    private void attachDatabaseReadListener() {
        if (mChildEventListener == null) {
            mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Photos friendlyMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(Photos.class);
                    contactsAdapter.add(friendlyMessage);
                }

                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            mMessagesDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
        }
    }
}
```

PhotosAdapter

```
public class PhotosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotosAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Photos> photosList;
    private Context context;
    public static final String Position="AdapterPosition";

    public PhotosAdapter(List<Photos> contactsList, Context context) {
        this.photosList = contactsList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public PhotosAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PhotosAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Photos contacts = photosList.get(position);


        Glide.with(context).load(contacts.getPhotoUrl()).into(holder.contactimageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return photosList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public ImageView contactimageView;
        private final Context context;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            context = itemView.getContext();
            contactimageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           /* Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra(Position,getAdapterPosition());
            context.startActivity(intent);*/
        }


       public void add(Photos photos){
        photosList.add(photos);
    }
}
```

Photos

```
public class Photos {
  private String photoUrl;

  public Photos() {
  } 

  public Photos(String photoUrl) {
    this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
  }

  public String getPhotoUrl() {
    return photoUrl;
  }

  public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
    this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
  }
}
```

This is my code. I am uploading an image on click of `FloatingAction` button to `Firebase` Storage.The image gets uploaded successfully, but I am not able to retrieve the image to the `ImageView` of my `RecyclerView`. What am I doing wrong? I am also able to see url of image in Storage.Still not able to retrieve message in imageview of recyclerview. Please help.......

Comment: when you are adding photo to photoList?
       public void add(Photos photos){
        photosList.add(photos);
    }

Answer (score 0):

you can try this also:-

```
yourFragment.isResumed()
```